# Collapsing a Midnight Commander directory tree

Tags: mc

When using Midnight Commander and making my left panel a directory tree, I open a directory and it expands with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again nothing happens. This is a fresh install of `mc` on Ubuntu 19.04. How do I collapse the directory tree in Midnight Commander's directory tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Enter</kbd> does two things in the directory tree: it loads the directory’s contents, and adds the subdirectories to the tree. There’s no direct opposite operation, but there are two ways to get back to the previous state:

- the first is to forget the directory, with <kbd>F3</kbd>; that also removes the parent directory from the tree (not the disk!), so you’ll need to go back to the parent and rescan with <kbd>F2</kbd>;
- the second is to navigate in dynamic mode, with <kbd>F4</kbd>; then you’ll only see the tree starting from the currently-selected directory, and pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> will hide the previously-opened tree.

Comment: this is useful, F3 to forget and reload parent